# Is there a way to get rid of that high pitched squelch from my laptop?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I have an earlier HP elitebook that I notice produces a high pitch squelch that some people my not even notice. It gets pretty annoying when you have two of them together. I feel like I have dog hearing.

Anyways, I think it might be the cpu or gpu - one of the two. I'm thinking it might be the nature of them. It is constant.

Is there a way to get rid of it. I notice that my later laptop doesn't make this noise.

Btw all my laptops have ssds. Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if its the CPU  or GPU -its more likely to be power supply/regulation circuitry - particularly caps or coils.

Comment: Okay. So I guess there is no fixing it since that's gonna be integrated onto the motherboard :( Sometimes it's so piercing Maybe earplugs haha

Comment: You could consider getting it replaced under warranty if it bothers you a lot - it might only be that laptop that is faulty